# Parameter section similar to Input and Output

Tags: algorithm2e

I would like to create a "**Parameter**: ..." section, similar to the "**Input**: ..." and "**Output**: ..." sections in my algorithm description. The parameters are global, user-defined constants, known before the algorithm is run.

I have tried to define a new keyword with the text "Parameter" but of course that does the wrong thing (among others: the line is numbered but it should not be, everything behind the "Parameter:" is in italics but I don't want it to be).

**How can I create a parameter section similar to Input and Output?**

---

[Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179324/8599) almost does the right thing but I get a superfluous colon on a separate line.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,12pt,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,algoruled,boxed,lined]{algorithm2e}
\volume{00}
\firstpage{1}
\journalname{Some journal}

% Would work correctly with these lines:
% \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[linesnumbered,algoruled,boxed,lined]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwInOut{Parameter}{Parameters}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \KwIn{Some input}
  \Parameter{Some parameter}
  \KwOut{Some output}    
\caption{Some algorithm}\label{alg.mainLoop}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I guess it is some macro clash among the packages. Any workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
\SetKwInOut{Parameter}{parameter}
```

and then

```
\Parameter{<text>}
```

in you algorithms. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetKwInOut{Parameter}{parameter}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwData{Left}{left}
\SetKwData{This}{this}
\SetKwData{Up}{up}
\SetKwFunction{Union}{Union}
\SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
\Output{A partition of the bitmap}
\Parameter{A parameter for the algorithm}
\BlankLine
\emph{special treatment of the first line}\;
\For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{
\emph{special treatment of the first element of line $i$}\;
\For{$j\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $w$}{\label{forins}
\Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}\;
\Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}\;
\This$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j]$}\;
\If(\tcp*[h]{O(\Left,\This)==1}){\Left compatible with \This}{\label{lt}
\lIf{\Left $<$ \This}{\Union{\Left,\This}}\;
\lElse{\Union{\This,\Left}\;}
}
\If(\tcp*[f]{O(\Up,\This)==1}){\Up compatible with \This}{\label{ut}
\lIf{\Up $<$ \This}{\Union{\Up,\This}}\;
\tcp{\This is put under \Up to keep tree as flat as possible}\label{cmt}
\lElse{\Union{\This,\Up}}\tcp*[r]{\This linked to \Up}\label{lelse}
}
}
\lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}}
}
\caption{disjoint decomposition}\label{algo_disjdecomp}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the edit to the question, there's some incompatibility between `elsarticle` and the new definition; in this case, you can move the new definition inside the `algorithm` environment which can be done on a on-per-one basis or, as **Werner** suggested in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179320/parameter-section-similar-to-input-and-output/179324?noredirect=1#comment414278_179324), can be automated using

```
\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro{\@algocf@init}{\SetKwInOut{Parameter}{Parameters}} 
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,12pt,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,algoruled,boxed,lined]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro{\@algocf@init}{\SetKwInOut{Parameter}{Parameters}} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwIn{Some input}
\Parameter{Some parameter}
\KwOut{Some output}    
\caption{Some algorithm}\label{alg.mainLoop}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It almost OK but I get a superfluous colon; please check the updated question.

Comment: @Ali the code snippet you added to your question is useless, as it doesn't allow (upon suitable completion) to reproduce the problem. Please edit your question and add there a minimal, but *complete* document (like the one in my answer) allowing us to reproduce the problem mentioned.

Comment: OK, working on it. I was hoping for a trivial mistake on my part that's already obvious from those lines... I will post an SSCCE soon.

Comment: Done, thanks for your patience. It looks like a weird macro clash. Please check.

Comment: @Ali Thanks for providing the example. Indeed, there seems to be some incompatibility with `elsarticle`; I've updated my answer providing a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Unfortunately another issue came up: Now the indentation is messed up but I will post another, separate question. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ali You're welcome! I've updated my answer with another workaround that shouldn't affect the indentation, though I've not tested this. If problems persist, then yes, the best thing to do would be to open a new question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: What about `\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\@algocf@init}{\SetKwInOut{Parameter}{Parameters}}
\makeatother
`?

Comment: @Werner yes, thanks. I added your suggestion to my answer (please, don't delete you comment, since I linked to it in the answer).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Unfortunately, it is still messed up. I will submit a new question with an SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). I greatly appreciate your help so far.

Comment: @Ali I didn't find that question on your SE profile. Did you actually follow up on this?

Comment: @polynomial_donut No, I didn't. :( I just submitted the paper with the messed up layout, and forgot about it. And apparently it is still an issue, or you would not be asking about it. :( Sorry!